# KeyListener for 2 objects

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

Is it possible to have `KeyListener` inside class? For example I have class `Pad` with `KeyListener`. In `Gam`e class I create 2 `Pads` and want to move it.

Comment: Please provide more details and code snippets if possible.

Comment: It is possible to have a `KeyListener` inside another class. It is probably also possible to obtain what you really want without having the `KeyListener` inside the class; but you have not explained neither what your situation and your design are, nor have I understood your higher goal.

Comment: *"Is it possible to have `KeyListener` inside class?"* Yes. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).